# React this.props."function" is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I spent a lot of time on stack overflow and I still can't find my error despite my research. I want to user a method from a external librairy called "mxGraph", and I want to add a listener of my graph component

Here is my error: "this.props.graph.getSelectionModel is not a function"

Here is my code:

```
class StyleModificationBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fontValue: 16,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initListener();
    }

    initListener = () => {
        this.props.graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, this.onSelected);
    };

    onSelected = evt => {
        console.log(evt.cells[0]);
    };
}
```

I've tried everything, bind my initLister function in the constructor and I've tried again and again to bind my initLister function in the constructor and I've tried again and again.

Could someone help me?

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(this.props.graph)` and `console.log(this.props.graph.getSelectionModel)`?

Comment: The error says it all, `this.props.graph.getSelectionModel` is not a function.

Comment: Perhaps check the graph object you are passing down as a prop in the first place in that case. console.log it in your parent component.

Comment: No, just write console.log(this.props.graph) and tell what you see in the console. The issue is with getSelectionModel.

Comment: Could it be that the `graph` prop and/or its property `getSelectionModel` are valid eventually, but by the time the component is rendered for the _first time_ it doesn’t yet receive the right value in `graph` prop (i.e., an object of expected shape), which makes it throw a TypeError and prevents further execution?

Comment: Rishat I think you are rigth, but do you have some advice for fix this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is very strange, the first console.log (the one in the constructor) returns an empty object while the one in the increase function returns my mxGraph object and this function works perfectly.

```
class StyleModificationBar extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                fontValue: 16,
            };
            console.log(this.props.graph); // This one print a empty object
        }

        increaseFontValue = () => {
            console.log(this.props.graph); // This one print a full mxGraph object
            let cellProperties = this.props.graph.getCellStyle(this.props.graph.getSelectionCell());
            this.setState({fontValue: parseInt(cellProperties.fontSize) + 1},
                () => {
                    this.props.graph.setCellStyles("fontSize", this.state.fontValue)
                })
        }

        decreaseFontValue = () => {
            let cellProperties = this.props.graph.getCellStyle(this.props.graph.getSelectionCell());
            this.setState({fontValue: parseInt(cellProperties.fontSize) - 1},
                () => {
                    this.props.graph.setCellStyles("fontSize", this.state.fontValue)
                })
        }
```